# REQUEST query with more then one field

Tags: php, html, mysql

I want this query to request extension and department from my database. I can make it work with only one of them but not both.

code:

```
$this_user_ext =$_REQUEST['extension'];  <----This line here I need 'department' in it as well.

    // sending query
    mysql_query("DELETE FROM users WHERE extension = '$this_user_ext'")
    or die(mysql_error());          


    if($_POST['action'])
{

include('maildelete.php');

$extension=$_POST['extension'];

header("Location: index.php");
}
```

Comment: you want to use at same time or different & can you explain more

Comment: I would like to use it as the same time if possible please. Thank you sir @gaurav

Comment: than you can use as like  another variable `$a = $_REQUEST['department']` at same time.

Comment: I dont need to add it to the current REQUEST? I thought you had to add it like ['extension', 'department']

Comment: Thank you sir :) @gaurav

Comment: Please don't use `mysql` functions , prefer `mysqli` or `PDO`  & instead of `$_REQUEST` use `$_POST` or `$_GET` according to your need.

Comment: I will update it sir. one more thing if i may @gaurav in the line "DELETE FROM users WHERE extension = '$this_user_ext'" If I wanted to add department to it. would be just be AND department = '$department'?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/135659/discussion-between-gaurav-and-redz).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So basically, you want something like:

```
$this_user_ext = $_REQUEST['extension'];
$this_user_dep = $_REQUEST['department'];
//please escape and/or validate the request values

$query = "DELETE FROM users WHERE "
    . "extension = '$this_user_ext' "
    . "AND department = '$this_user_dep';";
mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
//please don't use mysql_query(), because it is deprecated
```

Comment: exactly thank you. Is there a way to pop up a message if the 2 don't match? like they got the right extension but the wrong department?

Comment: You would need to verify that via some static array (if there is small number of distinct values), or via `SELECT` statement to fetch the data from database and if the result is empty, print error. Query example: `SELECT * FROM users WHERE extension = '$this_user_ext' AND department = '$this_user_dep';`